# JQuery remove duplicate from array where string contains same text

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with X number of items.  Each has variables separated by a pipe character.  In a loop I can split on the pipe to get the second item; but how do I splice to remove the duplicate.

```
"Sometext|22621086|address|333629dc87894a7ea7df5291fa6d1836|PC_E|1803"
"Sometext2|22622138|working|d3e70175ffe942568cd21f1cf96f4d63|PC_E|1803"
"Sometext3|22622138|working|851946e6325445da99c113951590f714|PC_E|1803"
```

Results should be this.

```
"Sometext|22621086|address|333629dc87894a7ea7df5291fa6d1836|PC_E|1803"
"Sometext2|22622138|working|d3e70175ffe942568cd21f1cf96f4d63|PC_E|1803"
```

Note that the duplicate 22622138 is a random number so the solution needs to work for any number in this location (it's always in the arr[1] position).

This is what I tried:

```
$.each(arr_transcript, function (i, e) {
            if (e.length != 0) {
                var arr = e.split("|")
                var i = arr_transcript.indexOf(arr[1]);
                if (i != -1) {
                    arr_transcript.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a map of the numbers you want to check against, and then filter based on that

```js
var arr_transcript = [
    "Sometext|22621086|address|333629dc87894a7ea7df5291fa6d1836|PC_E|1803",
    "Sometext2|22622138|working|d3e70175ffe942568cd21f1cf96f4d63|PC_E|1803",
    "Sometext3|22622138|working|851946e6325445da99c113951590f714|PC_E|1803"
];

var map = arr_transcript.map(function(text) { 
    return text.split('|')[1];
});

var filtered = arr_transcript.filter(function(item, index) {
    return index === map.lastIndexOf( map[index] );
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: the georg solution works; however if you obfuscate your script through an online tool, they break.  I ultimately switched to adeneo's solution and the obfuscators work!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a generic function:

```js
function uniqBy(a, key) {
    let seen = new Set();
    return a.filter(item => {
        let k = key(item);
        return !seen.has(k) && seen.add(k);
    });
};

var data = [
    "Sometext|22621086|address|333629dc87894a7ea7df5291fa6d1836|PC_E|1803",
    "Sometext2|22622138|working|d3e70175ffe942568cd21f1cf96f4d63|PC_E|1803",
    "Sometext3|22622138|working|851946e6325445da99c113951590f714|PC_E|1803"
];

var result = uniqBy(data, item => item.split('|')[1]);

console.log(result)
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9229821/989121) for more info.

Comment: What exactly is `item => item.split('|')[1]`  and `a.filter(item =>` doing here? Specifically what is the role of `=>` I know it's use in php but have never seen it used in javascript before

Comment: @DelightedD0D: those are [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Thanks, wish I could upvote again just for that, very interesting!!